# Is it possible to require "initial unlock" for smart lock

Tags: security, samsung-galaxy-s-6, smart-lock

Is it possible to enforce initial unlock while using smart lock?

For example, I'm using smart unlock with "Trusted places" and I would prefer it didn't automatically unlock when I get in range of my trusted place. Theoretically that means someone could steal my phone, follow me home and gain access to it when he gets in range.

Can I somehow enforce "initial unlock" even when I come in range of the trusted place. After that initial unlock, the device should remain unlocked until you leave the trusted area.

Comment: I'm saddened by the lack of answers to this question. I just posted a different question, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164343/smart-lock-and-multi-factor-authentication, where clearly we have the same concerns in mind.