# Smart Lock, and multi-factor authentication?

Tags: security, lock-screens, disk-encryption, smart-lock

I am using Marshmallow, and I use the built-in encryption mechanism.  Typing my password every time the screen locks is a pain.  I would like to leverage [Smart Lock](https://get.google.com/smartlock/) to have the following ideal situation:

- If my phone is far away from me, I'd like the phone to immediately lock; thus requiring a password to decrypt. **(This way, if my phone is lost, or even stolen, then my data will be safe.)**
- If my phone is nearby me, I'd like it to simply "soft lock" my screen; i.e., require either a PIN or facial recognition to unlock the screen, but not my full password. **(This way, if I leave my my phone at my desk at work, for example, someone sneaky can't snatch it and snoop at my text messages or who knows what.)**

Before I go on a wild goose chase, can someone please tell me if this setup is possible with Android?

Comment: As I feared, the answer is most likely that there's no such thing as a "hard lock screen" in Android.  Unfortunately, the only one that exists is after rebooting the device.  More information here: https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2016/11/24/android-n-encryption/

Comment: Worst-case, you could use tasker to reboot your phone whenever you leave it alone for too long.

Comment: @Ajedi32: If someone explained how to do this, I'd be up for trying it.

Comment: @Ajedi32: Actually, I think that'd be drastic. What would be great is if it auto-rebooted once it's too far away from me.